# Recognize Image clicking over in Raphael

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, raphael

I have a canvas where using raphael I'm going to draw some images.
The images's names are in a list: `images_list` and I will draw three images for row. All the images have the same dimensions, are equaly spaced and are .png files (no vector).
Some example code:

```
var paper_images_list = Raphael(canvas_images_list, '100%', '100%');
var images_for_row=3
var y_max=Math.ceil(image_list.length/images_for_row)*40
paper_images_list.setSize(div_width, y_max);
for (var i=0; i<image_list.length; i++) {
        var col=parseInt(i/images_for_row)
        var y=col*40
        var x=(i-images_for_row*col)*40
        var image = paper_images_list.image('/media/images/'+image_list[i], x, y, 33, 27);
    };
```

What I want: clicking on an image I want to know which image that is, for use it in another paper/canvas.

I'm using Raphael because I thinked it could make that easy but maybe I'm wrong. Is it possible to recognize the image just clicking over it?

If not, I can find the coordinates of the click and calculate which image there is, but I don't need Raphael for that, right? There are better solutions?

I'm using Phyton3.5, Django 1.9, Javascript/JQuery, Windows7

Comment: Your click handler should be able to show which it is. If you have a click handler on each element, then 'this' will point to the respective image. If you have a generic handler, then you can probably see what it is by looking at event.target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ian I found it's so simple like:

```
document.getElementById('canvas_images_list').onclick=function(event) {
    var myimage = event.target
    if (myimage.tagName == 'image') {
        myimage = myimage.href.baseVal;
    };
};
```

The `if` statement excludes the clicks outside any images